# Chrome local overrides require/import?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In the Google Chrome devtools local overrides feature, I'd like to import/require an external js file from within the overrode js file.

I've tried the following three ways so far, but no chance.

**1. require**

placing `const hoge = require("./config.js");`, got an error `ReferenceError: require is not defined`

**2. import**

placing `import hoge from "./config.js"`, an error `Cannot use import statement outside a module`

**3. axios/get**

let's say the overrode file path is `https://example.com/web/scripts/pages/watch/modern/main.js`

so I placed a new file on `file:///C:/path_to_chrome_devtools_override/example.com/web/scripts/pages/watch/modern/config.js`

then from an arbitrary position in the source file, run `axios.get("https://example.com/web/scripts/pages/watch/modern/config.js");`

as a last resort I expected to see the text but I got a 404 not found error. `AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404',`

~~

so, how can I get to work this? is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: "https://example.com/web/scripts/pages/watch/modern/config.js" does indeed return 404. Are you sure this script exists? before trying to use it..

Comment: I mean the path doesn't exist on the web, but on the local overrides path (e.g. `file:///C:/path_to_chrome_devtools_override/example.com/web/scripts/pages/watch/modern/config.js`);

Comment: I just confirmed that I **can** make a `axios` request to a URL on the web; But still I'm curious that how to import "local" js files within the local overrides, since 1. some sites doesn't allow me to `axios` 2. in some situations the internet may not available or cannot fetch the file on the web.